# 3d object into 2d image

Tags: masking

Coming from architectural background... what is the process of masking a 3d rendered object and placing it into a 2d image in a cityscape, where some part of the 2d image will be in front of the rendered 3d building?

Available source for learning (tutorial) will be helpful.

Comment: If you want to hide some parts of the 3D scene you can use some objects that have the Holdout option enabled, and also enable the Transparent option in the Render panel > Film

Comment: Yeah holdout is a quick and efficient way to place a render in a photography. If you want a realistic result (shadows, occlusion, bounce light) you'll likely want to roughly model the photograph projecting the texture from the camera using a tool like fspy

Comment: I am using fspy for realistic results. I have the 3d building on top of the 2d image which serves as a background. The issues I have is combing them both, where parts of the 2d image will cover parts of the 3d object (bring them in front of the 3d object). If someone can suggest some available tutorials regarding my particular situation, will be very helpful. @Gorgious

Comment: You could project your images on flat objects? Same for the background